# How can I download an MP3 to my phone instead of opening it in a music player?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, downloading, mp3, samsung-epic-4g

I'm trying to download podcast MP3s to my phone so I can listen to them in my car. Ideally, I'd like to be able to Chrome-to-Phone them from my computer at home, and then choose  to download and play them back from my device once I get in my car.

The problem is that when I send an MP3 URL to my phone, the browser only gives me the option of playing the audio directly in a media player. This is a really poor experience because it can't properly buffer the podcast file for smooth playback and it doesn't seem to allow me to play in the background.

[image: Screenshot of options when downloading MP3]

I tried both [Download All Files](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.hwkrbbt.downloadall) and using [ASTRO](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro)'s "Enable Browser Downloads". The screenshot above was taken with both apps installed. I've also tried using [Google Listen](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.listen&hl=en) to download podcasts, but I can never seem to use that without the download getting corrupted or the app crashing in some way.

Does anyone know what I need to do to be able to download MP3s instead of just playing them back immediately?

Comment: Have you tried using a different browser?

Comment: @eldarerathis I've tried both the stock CM browser and Dolphin HD. Both behave the same.

Comment: For what it's worth, this worked for me™.  Note that I downloaded an MP3 from DropBox (https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/music/knocker.mp3?w=894245c0, although you'll probably get "Access Denied" if you try that URL), and I was using Android 4.  But: I clicked the "Chrome To Phone" button, my phone chirped, and I saw the little downward-pointing animated arrow, quickly replaced by a notification that said "Download Complete".

Comment: You can try ADM download manager. Or hold URL and press *save link*.

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to Chrome-to-Phone a page *containing* the link to the mp3 you want? If so, Dolphin (and most most every Android browser) will allow you to "save link as" (or similar) when you long-press on it. This will download the file instead of trying to play or stream it.

More cumbersome solutions include downloading the mp3 you want on your PC then transferring via [Dropbox](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dropbox.android&hl=en) or syncing via [doubleTwist](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.doubleTwist.androidPlayer&hl=en) (or even their [AirSync](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.doubleTwist.androidPlayerProKey&hl=en) for-pay feature). Doubletwist even has its own built in podcast features much like iTunes. BigCaseyDog's answer about Amazon MP3 would be a very similar alternative to Dropbox.

FWIW, I'm a [Pocket Casts](https://market.android.com/details?id=au.com.shiftyjelly.pocketcasts&hl=en) fan for the purposes of this very question - I was stuck with the same problem you describe until I fell in love with their download feature, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

You could always upload the music to Amazon's free Cloud Player (included both online at www.amazon.com and in the Amazon MP3 app for Android) on your home computer. Then, download the Amazon MP3 app on your phone (if it's not already installed). Get it set up by typing in your Amazon account info, and sync in with your Cloud Drive, which lets you stream your music on your phone. Your music collection can either be streamed in the cloud, downloaded to the SD Card, or played with any media player on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to do this (without signing up for a new service) seems to be installing [Opera Mobile](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.opera.browser). Opera has the ability to download files instead of just using Android's default Intents menu for MP3s.

According to comments in the original question, it looks like Android 4.0 can do this natively.