# How to download an audio file from a web site?

Tags: audio, downloading

Is there a way to download an audio file, such as a mp3-file from the Android browser to the device so I could listen to it later when I'm offline? Is there a way I should program the web site to make this possible?

I'm *not* looking for an additional app to help me achieve this.

Comment: Related: [How can I download an MP3 to my phone instead of opening it in a music player?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17595/1465)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your android browser `long click` on MP3 file link or any audio link and click on `Save Link`. It will be downloaded to your phone and it will be stored in **`download folder`** in your sdcard.

Hope it will help you.